# Calculate the Probability of a call being answered

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, conditional-probability, marketing

We do B2B telemarketing and our main goal is to call someone at a time when the person actually answers the call.

I have divided 8 to 6 workday into ten one-hour blocks. Some people tend to answer the calls in the morning and some in the afternoon.

So, I have created following features to calculate the probability of each one-hour block:

```
1) Day of the week
2) Season (Winter, Spring, Summer, and Fall)
3) Job Role of the Person
4) Job Function
5) Timezone (Only US)
6) Account Size (based on Employee count)
7) Ten One-Hour Block (Target Variable)
```

I have tried various algorithms to get the probability from Bayes' Classifier to Random Forest.

The output probability of these classifiers make sense but the probabilities of few one-hour blocks are very close to each other and I would like to know the way to distinctly identify the probability of a person to answer the call given a call block.

Here, I need your advice on feature engineering or problem formation.

Also, if anyone has done any research on in this area of behavioral analytics, I would really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Is the current output necessarily a problem? Perhaps it's true that the likelihood of answering over those few one-hour blocks really doesn't change, in which case your system is performing correctly. Do you have an evaluation metric to assess how well the system is performing? You could use calibration to determine, on average, how well the predicted probabilities match up with the true likelihood of answering.

Comment: The current output is not actually a problem. But the problem with the current output is that some call blocks probabilities are very close to one another and I want three clear distinct one-hour blocks. If I want were to convert one-hour block to half-hour block the probability values further lowers. So, I believe I might need a better problem formulation or features to address this problem. Btw, I never heard of calibration. Can you provide some more details about it? My evaluation metric right is the "Log-Loss".

Comment: You can do a search for "calibrated probability assessment" to find out more. Basically, you bin all the predictions by likelihood (e.g. 0-20%, 21-40%, 41-60%, etc), and then within each bin, you determine the actual response rate. If your classifier is well-calibrated, the response rate should be within the bin range. So, for any hours that are classified as 80-100% likely to respond, around 90% should have actual response. Note that while calibration is a desirable property of probabilistic classifiers, it doesn't make any statements about overall accuracy.

Comment: This makes so much sense and is definitely helpful. Thank you for that but the problem I am facing is that none of my hour blocks is getting probability score more than 24%. The classifier is not able to confidently identify any hour block with a higher probability based on the features I have so far. That is the reason I need more features which I am struggling to find.